# Adding prefix to each variadic template argument

Tags: c++, templates, move, perfect-forwarding

I have the following code:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
    bar(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

It turns out that inside the `foo` function, I want to add some constant prefix to the start of each arg:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
    bar(prefix + std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This compiles, but is this code valid in its state? This is no longer perfect forwarding, right? I think the bar function will always be called with an rvalue argument.

Assuming `operator+` is defined for Args and prefix's type, and both types are compatible.

Comment: You are perfect forwarding your arguments to `operator+`. What it does with them is anyone's guess.

Comment: I guess that `operator+` returns by value. In that case, `bar` receives rvalue arguments.